# What's going on with the question "Change of measure"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, homework

A homework question posted 2 hours ago has been locked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21853/change-of-measure.  Is it the level of the question (i.e., graduate level) that earned it this designation or is there a distinction between the manner in which it was asked and other homework questions?

It looks like there has been quite a lot of discussion about how to handle hw questions, so I might have missed some community decision that would make it clear why this question was locked.  It just seemed quick, giving the OP less than 2 hours to address the issues raised in the comments.

Comment: I, for one, have no sympathy with anyone who wants us to solve their homework for them. It's also not fair to the other students.

Comment: I see now that the questioner has a history of posting poorly motivated homework problems with no evidence of having attempted anything. In a vacuum, it just seemed a little quick, but now I see there was some important context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say, the questioner posted several other poorly motivated homework questions yesterday and did not listen to multiple users asking them to stop. I locked the newest question, which was then posted [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55324/measure-theory-problem-closed), and I suspended and e-mailed the offending user.

We don't have a solid homework policy, but I am pretty sure that whatever it could be, this kind of behavior falls outside it.

Comment: Some sort of note to that effect, pointing to something on meta, or some kind of explanation as to why the question is locked might be helpful (since it's not at all obvious on the face of the question).

Comment: We do have a non-solid homework policy. It is [somewhat nebulously linked to from the FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange). (Yes, I know the links there to the various answers are broken. But I'm a bit too sleepy now to fix them.)